# If Range contains Zero or Blank Cell when trying to run apps script - ALERT - Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range A1:F that 1 person fills in with numbers & words. If he tries to run the script when done - script looks at the range A1:F first, and if a ZERO or BLANK CELL exists anywhere in that range, a popup ALERT tells him to "fix range and then rerun script"

see link - In link you can see B5 has a 0 and I have highlighted it
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nqmlh3nuXM3l0CbAUBzCx7YlNA_T0K7QvNxFL-LrUHk/edit#gid=0

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's you question?

Comment: Cooper - I need a piece of code that will look over a range and highlight if a cell contains a ZERO or BLANK CELL

Answer (score 1):

```
function highliteZeroOrBlank(sheetName,rangeInA1Notation) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetName=sheetName||ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var rangeInA1Notation=rangeInA1Notation||ss.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rg=sh.getRange(rangeInA1Notation);
  var v=rg.getValues();
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  v.forEach(function(r,i){r.forEach(function(c,j){if(c==0||c==''){sh.getRange(row+i,col+j).setBackground('#ffff00');}});});
}
```